# Probability in a knock-out tournament

Tags: probability

Maths newbie so please go gently. Imagine if you would:

4 teams in the semi-final of a soccer tournament A,B,C,D.

A,B and C all have 20% chance of winning the tournament. D however, is the favourite with a 40% chance of winning.

The lunch time game is between A and B where A wins.

So...the question is how do I calculate the new probabilities of B,C or D now winning before the evening semi between C and D

Second question if I can? what the probabilities after D wins the evenings semi match?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The lunch time game is between A and B where A wins?" - Is that a question or a fact???

Comment: In addition, it is not clear in your question whether those $20,20,20,40$ probabilities have been determined **before** the semi-finals fixing (meaning that A, B and C are equally good), or **after** the semi-finals fixing (meaning that C is slightly better than A and B because it's about to play D and still has the same probability of winning the tournament as A and B have).

Comment: sorry, that is a fact. ? was in error

Comment: Was the lunchtime game between A and B their semifinal match?  In other words:  After this match, is B knocked out of the tournament?

Comment: 20,20,20 and 40 were the probabilities before any semi game was played.

Comment: Hi John, yes the lunchtime game was their semi where B is knocked out and A moves into the final

Comment: I said "fixed", not "played". What I meant to ask is, were these the probabilities before anyone knew who was going to play against who in the semi-finals?

Comment: no, these were set after the last round was played and all these fixtures were known about.

Comment: @HWG there is an incredible amount of misunderstanding in the answers on this question. Please, please believe in the work provided by myself and Graham Kemp. We are using actual math to solve this problem. Everybody else is making some weird pseudo argument based on projections of their personal opinions.

Comment: @user166967: Graham Kemp agrees with the rest of the world that D's probability remains unchanged at $40%$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a nod to @TonyK that this real world problem is impossible, I will treat it as a pure mathematical question.

Before the game was played:
$$P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=0.2$$
and
$$P(D)=0.4$$

It was a given that in order to win, Team D must win its semi and would play either A or B in the final. Assuming that its chances against either are the same, what has changed by now knowing that Team A won the semi?

**Nothing**

Team D still has $P(D)=0.4$.

By similar reasoning Team C still has $P(C)=0.2$.

Which means $P(A)=0.4$

Shame on those who downvoted @Raja!

Comment: You are violating the assumption that A and C have the same probability of winning the tournament.

Comment: Anybody having the urge to reply to the above comment should first read graydad's answer below (and the ensuing comments, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, this kind of question is impossible to answer, because there may be unknown factors. Suppose Team D has a weakness against Team A, so that it is more likely to lose against Team A than Team B, even though Team A will only beat Team B half of the time. This skews the probabilities, making an exact calculation impossible.

But let's make the approximation that Team A and Team B are equally difficult to beat (which is reasonable on the basis of their pre-tournament chances). Then obviously it doesn't make any difference to Team D's chances whether A or B advances to the final, so its probability of winning is still 40%.

Answer (score 0):

Before the evening semi final between C and D, Probability of A winning is 40% (sum of probabilities of A and B), C winning is 20% (unchanged) and D winning is 40% (unchanged).

Probability of D winning the evening semifinal should be 66.66%. ( It has double the chances as compared with the opponent C)

---

Let us understand this situation with an example. let us assume 60 parallel worlds. (60 because that is convenient to me.) These worlds are similar but the outcomes of an experiment can be different.   
 Now, according to question, out of 60 worlds, A, B and C win in 12 worlds each, and D wins in the tournament in 24 worlds. Also, A wins the semi-final against B in 30 worlds and B wins a semi-final against A in rest of the 30. Similarly C wins a semi-final against D in 20 worlds, whereas D wins Semi-final in 40 worlds. Now, C plays final in 20 worlds, so it plays 10 against A and 10 against B.
 
 Now, C has to win in 12 worlds, so it wins 6 against A and 6 against B. This means A wins only 4 matches out of the 10 it plays with C. 'A' also has to complete its 12 victories. A plays with D in the Final in 20 worlds, out of which, A wins 8, D wins 12. D wins 12 again with B, hence completing its 24 matches. 
 Now, in the question, B loses the semi-final against A. So we can ignore all the 30 worlds in which B wins against A. That leaves ust with just 30 worlds, in which A defeats C in 4 worlds, C defeats A in 6, C wins in 6 worlds out of 30, A defeats D in 8 worlds, and hence gains a grand sum of 12, and finally D wins against A in 12 worlds. So, A wins 40%, C 20% and D 40%.

Comment: I am adding an example to illustrate ho I see this problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

$\newcommand{\P}[1]{\operatorname{\mathsf P}\left[#1\right]}$
We want to know the probabilities that A, C, or D will win, given that we now know that B will not, **and** that A was matched with B in the semi-finals.

We shall use **Bayes' Theorem** to calculate the conditional probabilities.

Let $A_B$ mean A is victorious in a game with B, and $M_{ABCD}$ mean A is matched with B and C is matched with D in the semi-finals.

If we assume that the three ways to match the teams have equal weighting, then $\P{M_{ABCD}}=\P{M_{ACBD}}=\P{M_{ADBC}}=\frac 1 3$

Further since the probabilities of A, B, and C ultimately winning are equal, then by symmetry:

$\P{A_B}=\P{A_C}=\P{B_C}=\P{C_B}=\P{C_A}=\P{B_A}=\frac 12$

$p=\P{D_A}=\P{D_B}=\P{D_C}=1-\P{A_D}=1-\P{B_D}=1-\P{C_D}$

$\therefore \P{D} = p^2= 0.4$

We wish to find the probabilities that:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Team $D$ wins the final } & \text{ on the condition that $A$ faced and won against $B$ in the semi final round.}
\\
\P{D\mid M_{ABCD}, A_B} &= \frac{\P{M_{ABCD}, A_B, D_C, D_A}}{\P{M_{ABCD}, A_B}}
\\ & = \frac{\P{M_{ABCD}}\P{A_B}\P{D_C}\P{D_A}}{\P{M_{ABCD}}\P{A_B}}
\\ & = \P{D_C}\P{D_A}
\\ & = 0.4
\\[3ex]
\text{Team $C$ wins the final } & \text{ on the condition that $A$ faced and won against $B$ in the semi final round.}
\\
\P{C\mid M_{ABCD}, A_B} & = \P{C_D}\P{C_A}
\\ & = \frac{1-\sqrt{0.4}}2
\\ & = 0.183772...
\\[3ex]
\text{Team $A$ wins the final } & \text{ on the condition that $A$ faced and won against $B$ in the semi final round.}
\\
\P{A\mid M_{ABCD}, A_B} & = \P{A_C}\P{C_D}+\P{A_D}\P{D_C}
\\ & = \frac 12 (1-\sqrt{0.4})+(1-\sqrt{0.4})\sqrt{0.4}
\\ & = \frac {0.2+\sqrt{0.4}}2
\\ & \approx 0.416228...
\end{align}$$

---

**Remarks**

Two separate influences acted to change the chances of victory.  One condition was which teams were matched against D in the semi-final.  The other condition was how many further challenges awaited the team.

Team D's chance of victory remained at $0.4$ because they still faced two challenges of equal difficulty to those they had before the matching was decided.  The identity of their opposing teams did not affect their chances, so the outcome of Teams' A and B match did not affect their chance of victory in either of their challenges.

Team C's chance of victory was *decreased* because had become certain that they must face team D.  Their chances were decreased once the match up with D was decided; it was not influenced by the team A's victory.

Team A's chance of victory was *increased* because they had only one more challenge to overcome. (It had also become less certain that they would face team D, the chance of that depending on the outcome of teams C and D's match).

---

### Addendum

I should note that this symmetry argument only works if we assume A, B, and C were equally likely to be matched against D in the semi-finals.  If we assume instead that the match between A and B, C and D was predetermined before the initial probabilities were assessed, then we will have six unknowns in four linear equations.

Comment: I gave the exact same answer as you about 6 hours ago and nobody believed me. I hope OP sees your answer for the sake of this thread!

Comment: Could you tell me, according to your method, what is the probability that A wins if the the final game is between A and C?

Comment: @Raja, $\mathsf P(A \mid A\cup C) = \dfrac{ \mathsf P(A) }{ \mathsf P(A) + \mathsf P(C) } = \dfrac{20}{20+20} = 50\%$

Comment: Intuitively, this cannot be right - A only has to win one game but C & D must win 2 - given that A and C were equally likely *before* A won a semi, A must now be more likely than B.

Comment: I think that If the final game is between A and C, C has more chances of victory. I will tell you why. Suppose A defeats B in the first game. The probability of this to happen is 50%. Now, the probability that C defeats D and makes it to the final is 33.33%. Therefore, probability that A and C meet in the final is 1/6. The probability that C wins against 'A' is 1/10 ( and the probability that C wins against B is 1/10, so the total is 1/5, which is C's total chance.) So the probability that A wins against C in final is 1/6-1/10 = 1/15. If the final game is between A and C, C has 60% chance.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I think you may be conditioning on wrong event here. Here you have $B$ as event that team $B$ wins the tournament. Well $\neg B$ then corresponds to even that $B$ lose in semis or $B$ loses in the finals. But we want to condition on event that $B$ loses in semis (i.e. $B$ loses to $A$). Thus what you have for $P(D|\neg B)$ is the probability that D wins the tournament given B lost in semis or finals (thus this should actually increase probablity D winning)

Comment: @user159813 That *is* a good point.  I've modified the answer to reflect the added conditioning.

Comment: By your logic, if B had beaten A, then by symmetry D's chance would still be $0.416228...$ In other words, _whatever_ the result of the semifinal between A and B, D's chance of winning the tournament is miraculously increased. Which doesn't make any kind of sense. I have given up on trying to persuade user166967 that this is impossible, but you seem more sensible.

Comment: @Tony.  See the remarks.  D's chance of victory is 0.4 regardless as the team must still succeed in two matches against the equally ranked opponents.  However, I should note that the symmetry argument only works if we assume A, B, and C were initially equally likely to be matched against D in the semi finals.  If this was not the case, and the match up between A and B was known before the prior probabilities were assessed, then ....

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now. That interpretation hadn't occurred to me (that the probabilities were calculated before the semifinal draw was known). And I thought that your final probability was that of D winning the tournament, not A.

Answer (score -2):

Team D is still twice as likely to win as A and C, even though B is now out of the running. A and C have equal odds still. Letting $P_{X}$ denoting the probably that team X wins, then we can set up the equation $P_{D}+P_{A}+P_{C}=1$. But again we already know $P_{D}=2P_{A}=2P_{C}$, so we can replace $P_{A}$ and $P_{C}$ in the first equation with $\frac{1}{2}P_{D}$. Now we have $P_{D}+\frac{1}{2}P_{D}+\frac{1}{2}P_{D}=1$ and solving for $P_{D}$ yields $P_{D}=\frac{1}{2}$, or 50%. Now that we know $P_{D}$ we can solve for $P_{C}$ and $P_{A}$, and we'll find that $P_{A}$=$25$% = $P_{C}$. You can repeat this process to figure out the remaining part of your question.

Comment: Why will lose of team B in the semi final between A and B increase the probability of victory of team C from 0.2 to 0.25?

Comment: Team A and C have the same probability of winning right? Now that team B is defeated, there are only two teams that A and C (respectively) can lose to, whereas before there were three.

Comment: @user166967: "Team A and C have the same probability of winning right?" Of course not! Team A has scored a glorious victory over team B, which obviously increases its chances significantly.

Comment: @user166967:But now that team B is defeated, we get a hint that luck has favored team A (at least mathematical luck). This shows that team A has more chances over C now, although this was not the case before B's defeat.

Comment: Why exactly would that raise team A's chance of winning?

Comment: @Raja No, that is not how it works. OP introduced the problem as A,B and C have the SAME probability of winning the tournament. That does not change as the tournament progresses; there chances of winning remain equal until the end.

Comment: @user166967; On that basis, Team B's chance of winning the tournament is still 20%, even though it has been eliminated. Which doesn't look quite right.

Comment: @TonyK B is no longer competing. New odds can be calculated with the rule that A and C are just as likely to win, and D is twice as likely to win as either A or C.

Comment: @user166967: But A and C are not just as likely to win any more! Surely you can see that?

Comment: @TonyK Uh, no. Not how it works. I have provided the math above to explain my reasoning. I'd like to see the math that you used to work this out.

Comment: OK, let me try another tack. You claim that D's chance of winning the tournament is greater than it was before A beat B in the semifinal. By symmetry, if B had won, that would also have increased D's chance. Thus, whoever wins the semifinal between A and B, D's chance is increased! Are you happy with that?

Comment: That is exactly the same scenario that is already taking place. Had team B beaten team A, then team B would now have a 25% chance of winning, team C would have 25% chance of winning the tournament and D would still be at 50%.

Comment: I give up.${}{}$

Comment: All you have to do is show me your math. I will believe you when you have the numbers to back up what you say.